# Nothing happens when button is clicked in Web App ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, button

I am creating a Web application using ASP.NET WebForms using C# (4.5.2). I am using the basic template that offers login support. Well it was all working and I began adding things to the website and now all of a sudden buttons are not working throughout the entire website.

I have not added any references or anything along that. I have added some JavaScript files though. I have searched for hours trying to find fixes, but I either did not understand what they were saying to do, or when I attempted them, it did nothing or it just did not apply.

No matter what page I try to click a button on, nothing is happening. I click the button and the page does not try to load or nothing, it just sits there like I never clicked the button in the first place.

I have also realized that the button on the register page does work, but only when there is an error When there isn't any errors, then the button does nothing. When there are errors and the button is clicked, the page just sits there like nothing happened. Here is the code:

Register.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Account/Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
<p class="text-danger">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
</p>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a new account</h4>
    <hr />
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The confirm password field is required." />
            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password and confirmation password do not match." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Register.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using WebApp.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApp.Account
{
    public partial class Register : Page
{
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

             // !!! THIS IS FOR SHOPPING CART AND IS DISABED FOR TROUBLESHOOTING

            //using (WebApp.Logic.ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new WebApp.Logic.ShoppingCartActions())
            //{
              //  String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetCartId();
                //usersShoppingCart.MigrateCart(cartId, user.Id);
            //}

                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else 
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApp.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--<script src="Scripts/modallogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>

            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" visible="false" href="~/Admin/AdminPage">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/ProductList">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/ShoppingCart.aspx" id="cartCount">&nbsp;</a></li>

                    <li><p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Login</a></p></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/logo.jpg">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
            <div id="div-forms">

                <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                <form id="login-form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-login-msg">
                            <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <!-- <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required> -->
                        <!-- <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required> -->
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <!-- <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="login1_auth" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"></asp:Login> -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="login1_auth">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End # Login Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-lost-msg">
                            <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                            <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                <form id="register-form" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-register-msg">
                            <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                        <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                        <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                            <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Register Form -->

            </div>
            <!-- End # DIV Form -->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

    <!-- END OF MODAL LOGIN -->

    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site.Master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq;
using WebApp.Models;
using WebApp.Logic;

namespace WebApp
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
        var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
        Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
        if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
        {
            // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

            var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            };
            if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                responseCookie.Secure = true;
            }
            Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
        }

        Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
    }

    protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Set Anti-XSRF token
            ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
            ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
            if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            adminLink.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void login1_auth(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(Email.Text, Password.Text);

        if(e.Authenticated.Equals(true))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Email.Text, true);
            // LoginPopupExtener.Hide();

            if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
                Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString());

        }
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
        {
            string cartStr = string.Format("Cart ({0})", usersShoppingCart.GetCount());
            cartCount.InnerText = cartStr;
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }

    public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var _db = new WebApp.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Category> query = _db.Categories;
        return query;
    }
}

}
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I did disable it from the source. I added this before the problem arised, so here is the modallogin javascript code for the modal login that is in the nav bar as of right now:

```
$('#register_login_btn').click(function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
$('#login_lost_btn').click(function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
$('#lost_login_btn').click(function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
$('#lost_register_btn').click(function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
$('#register_lost_btn').click(function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

function modalAnimate($oldForm, $newForm) {
var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
var $newH = $newForm.height();
$divForms.css("height", $oldH);
$oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function () {
    $divForms.animate({ height: $newH }, $modalAnimateTime, function () {
        $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
    });
});
}

function msgFade($msgId, $msgText) {
    $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function () {
    $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
});
}

function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
    var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
    msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
    $divTag.addClass($divClass);
    $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
    $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
        $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
        $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
    }, $msgShowTime);
  }
});
```

Comment: You will need to post some code. Take a look here on how to properly ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have read that. As I said, I have no clue on what code you guys would even need for a issue like this seeing how it is on every single page on the website

Comment: Try looking at the dev tools on the page see if you are getting errors that might be disabling the buttons. If no errors try re moving JS files until functionality comes back. Then look through that file to see what might be causing it. debugger; and Console.log(); are your friends here.

Comment: Posting the code for the markup (.aspx) from login page and the code behind (.aspx.cs) will help better answer your question.